# APEX 5.1 Shuttle Output Truncated when Selecting Multiple Items

Tags: oracle-apex-5.1

If you select 2 values from a shuttle box in my sample application (https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=127798:21:109329984160014:::::), only one value is passed when transferring to a second page.

Example 1:

[image: APPLES and ORANGES selected]
APPLES and ORANGES are selected from shuttle1.

After 2 values are selected from shuttle1 and the Transfer button is pressed, the second page is displayed:
[image: Second page displays only APPLES]
Only APPLES is displayed.

Example 2:

[image: APPLES and ORANGES selected from shuttle1; HAMMER and NAILS selected from shuttle 2]

When 2 values are selected from shuttle1 and 2 values are selected from shuttle2 and the Transfer button is pressed, the second page is displayed:
[image: APPLES:ORANGES HAMMER]

In this example, the first shuttle passes APPLES:ORANGES to the 2nd page successfully, but the second shuttle passes only HAMMER, not HAMMER:NAILS.

Here is "code" for 1st shuttle:
[Item definition of 1st shuttle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kw1cH.jpg)
2nd shuttle is coded the same.

Here is "code" for Transfer button:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7wqL.jpg)

Here is the Branch define in Processing for 1st page:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlDIL.jpg)

Here is the field on the 2nd page that displays the passed values:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ahXR.jpg)

Comment: A blind guess: as shuttle item values are separated by a colon, you "forgot" to add **1** to your code (i.e. "number of words" is "number of colons + 1"). Though, as you were already told, it is difficult to debug code you can't see.

Comment: Here is my "code":